# Prevent user from modifying PK during PUT on REST endpoint

Tags: rest

Say I have the following object that a user can modify and `PUT` back to the endpoint.

**Endpoint**

`/customer/1234` where `1234` represents the PK value of the `Customer` entity being modified.

**Customer Entity**

```
{
    firstName: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Jones'
    ...
}
```

What keeps a user from modifying the request and sending it back to say `/customer/6789` and modifying an entity that have no right to modify?

Should you be checking that the user sending the `PUT` request back to the endpoint has the permissions to modify a `Customer` entity with an `ID` (PK) of `6789`?

I would assume that is the correct way to guard against this. But if so, then does the user have some sort of token issued during authentication that contains their user id/roles that would allow for checking against the sent back entity?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you check if the ID in the URL and the received object match you are not really protected. You need to perform authentication and verify in your backend if the user is allowed to perform the operation.

Of course it helps to match the IDs to detect fraud or miss-configured clients early in the process.